# Building a self-contained binary executable in Haskell with the dependency pandoc-citeproc

Tags: haskell, executable, cabal, pandoc-citeproc

I'm trying to compile a self-contained executable for a CLI tool written in Haskell. I followed [this](https://vrom911.github.io/blog/github-actions-releases) example to automatically build the executables for different operating systems with Github Actions using Cabal v3.2 and ghc v8.10.3.

This seems to work well and the executables do function superficially, but when actually applied on data, I get the following error message for the Linux version (I did not test the Windows build, but a colleague confirmed that the MacOS version has the same problem):

```
myprogram-0.3.2-Linux-ghc-8.10.3: 
/home/runner/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.3/pandoc-citeproc-0.17.0.2-
0607b6a3d51d41b0211d235af7fcf6eeb452dc6738775583dac1146860db61b1/
share/locales/locales-en-US.xml: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

This tells me, that pandoc-citeproc, on which I depend for BibTeX file parsing, has some additional data-files that do not get packed into the exectuable. Indeed I found the following sentence in the cabal-install documentation:

> Note that copied executables are not self-contained, since they might use data-files from the store. [source](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.2/nix-local-build.html?highlight=self#cabal-v2-install)

I did also read in the pandoc documentation, that it can be build in a way to already include these extra files.

> It is possible to compile pandoc such that the data files pandoc uses are embedded in the binary. The resulting binary can be run from any directory and is completely self-contained. With cabal, add -fembed_data_files to the cabal configure or cabal install commands.
> With stack, use --flag pandoc:embed_data_files. [source](https://pandoc.org/installing.html)

How do I build an executable with `cabal install` to prevent the error message above? I hope this is possible and I'm not missing something crucial here.

I tried

```
cabal install exe:myprogram --install-method=copy --overwrite-policy=always -fembed_data_files
```

to no avail.

Comment: *pandoc-citeproc* [has an `embed_data_files` flag](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-citeproc#flags) that appears to address this issue. I can't try to reproduce your issue right now, but I believe you can tell cabal-install to rebuild the *pandoc-citeproc* dependency with that flag by specifying it in [the `cabal.project` file of your project](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#package-configuration-options).

Comment: (While you did include `-fembed_data_files` in your command, I believe doing it that way would pass the flag to your package, and not to *pandoc-citeproc*.)

Comment: Thank you for these pointers! I added a file `cabal.project` with the content `package pandoc-citeproc\n    flags: +fembed_data_files` to the root of my project. Is this syntax correct?  Although this is really the only change I made, I seem to get an unrelated (?) error message now: `cabal: Internal error in target matching.` https://github.com/poseidon-framework/poseidon-hs/runs/1848274014 - Do you have an idea where this might be coming from?

Comment: Alright - I think I got it now. My `cabal.project` file lacked the lines `packages: ./*.cabal` and `with-compiler: ghc-8.10.3`. Also the flag has to be defined with `flags: +embed_data_files`, not `flags: +fembed_data_files`. Not exactly well documented, this whole ordeal, but maybe it's just me. So thank you very much @duplode. Feel free to put this into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped! I have promoted the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `embed_data_files` flag in the `cabal install exe:myprogram` command won't work, as cabal-install will pass it to your executable, rather than forwarding it to *pandoc-citeproc*. The most convenient way to set it up for good is through [the `cabal.project` file](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#package-configuration-options). If you don't have one, create it with the following minimal contents:

```
packages: ./*.cabal

package pandoc-citeproc
    flags: +embed_data_files
```

cabal-install will then recompile *pandoc-citeproc* dependency with the flag next time you ask for a build.